# glfw - is a realloc inside key_callback possible?

Tags: c, opengl, malloc, glfw

I am trying to make a drawing in openGL using glfw, the problem i'm facing is that to save the various coordinates of the points (i can't know their value or how many there will be in advance) i need to realloc a pointer to get more space to save them.
I need to realloc the pointer only when i press a button, hence i thought it made sense for the realloc to be in the `key_callback` function.
The problem is that, obviously, `int *pointer` isn't in the scope of `key_callback`so i can't realloc it directly there and i can't pass the `int *` to `key_callback` since it's a glfw fucntion that has specific arguments that i can't change.
My question is, should i declare `int *pointer = malloc` outside of main (globally) so that it's visible from both `main` and `key_callback`, increase a global variable inside `key_callback` and do something like `if (new_variable_value != old_variable_value){realloc}` inside main or there exist a third alternative that i didn't think of?

This is a skeleton of the code i have now: (obviously it won't work for many reasons, it's just to give you an idea of what i want to do)

```
key_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
        // do stuff
        // realloc pointer
}

int main(void) {

    int *pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (!pointer){
        free(pointer);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    GLFWwindow *window;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "Example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        //draw stuff

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }

    free(pointer);
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[User pointer](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_userptr):

> Each window has a user pointer that can be set with `glfwSetWindowUserPointer` and fetched with `glfwGetWindowUserPointer`. This can be used for any purpose you need and will not be modified by GLFW throughout the life-time of the window.
>
> The initial value of the pointer is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `pointer` as a global variable. This is the simplest possible fix.

You will need to initialize the pointer with `malloc()` within `main()` -- variables declared in the global scope can only be initialized to constant values, not function calls.

Comment: well i feel stupid now, i never use global variables so i somehow forgot that they can't be initialized to function calls...